# Wrap child elements into 2 divs equally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML code like this:

```
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>era</li>
<li>jeu</li>
<li>iuu</li>
<li>iij</li>
<li>emu</li>
<li>our</li>
```

I need to wrap them into 2  element equally (or like 5:6 if total is 11), like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>era</li>
    <li>jeu</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>iuu</li>
    <li>iij</li>
    <li>emu</li>
    <li>our</li>
</ul>
```

This should work on any amount of `<li>`'s. Can you suggest an elegant solution with jQuery?

Comment: And if the number of `<li>`'s is an odd number?

Comment: odd one can go in either left or right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var $li = $('li'),
    half = Math.floor($li.length/2);

$li.filter(function(i){ return i < half; }).wrapAll('<ul>');
$li.filter(function(i){ return i >= half; }).wrapAll('<ul>');
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qPjUy/)

Comment: Hello, this helped me but I used ceil() instead of floor() in case of 5 elements. ceil() does 3/2 and floor() does 2/3. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can divide by `2` and then round down or up (depending on whether you want `4:5` or `5:4`). After doing that, replace the `li`s with a `ul` containing the `li`s (first clone them, because otherwise the `li`s would have been moved around, and would not be able to be replaced because their original position is lost).

http://jsfiddle.net/TBhYX/

```
var li     = $('li'),
    amount = li.length,
    left   = amount / 2 | 0, // '| 0' rounds down
    right  = amount - left;

var leftElems = li.slice(0, left);
leftElems.replaceWith($('<ul>').append(leftElems.clone(true)));

var rightElems = li.slice(left, amount);
rightElems.replaceWith($('<ul>').append(rightElems.clone(true)));
```

---

You could also generalize these last two parts: http://jsfiddle.net/TBhYX/1/.

```
var li     = $('li'),
    amount = li.length,
    left   = amount / 2 | 0,
    right  = amount - left;

$.each([ [   0,   left],
         [left, amount]  ], function(i, v) {

    var elems = li.slice.apply(li, v);
    elems.replaceWith(
        $('<ul>').append(elems.clone(true))
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can use .each from jQuery and count them...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Then create the 2 ul, and then take only half of them and put them in the first ul. and then in the second...

Example code:

```
<div class="take_those">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Ein</li>
</div>
<ul class="first">
</ul>
<ul class="second">
</ul>
```

See what the elements are like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var total_items = 0;
    total_items = $(".take_those li").length;
    $(".take_those li").each(function(i) {
        if(i<(total_items/2)) {
            $(".first").append("<li>"+$(this).html()+"</li>");
        } else {
            $(".second").append("<li>"+$(this).html()+"</li>");
        }
    });
});
```

Or something like that...

Did this help you?